# How to hide Navigation Properties in DataGridView colums (EF)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have Navigation Properties of a Clients table but these properties are other tables that are bound to a client and shouldn't be seen in the Client GridView. I don't want to have to manually add a line of code for EVERY navigation property in all the 100 tables I have.

ex: `dataGridView.Columns("Orders").Visible = False`

Is there a way to hide the Navigation Properties from a datagridview?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`. By default it is `true` and that's causing the problem. Note that once you turn this feature off, you will have to define desired columns through code or preferably through `properties > columns` option.

Comment: I've read about this. But if you go this way, and are forced to generate ALL columns via code, since there are WAY more regular fields in all my tables then there are Navigation Properties, wouldn't it be easier to code the NP to visible=false (like in original post) rather then coding every since regular column for every table? (unless I didn't understand your method)